# How to convert existing NativeScript Angular project to Code Sharing project

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-codesharing, nativescript-schematics

All available tutorials talk about converting Angular Web Apps to codesharing Nativescript projects. I want to do the opposite.

I almost finished coding the mobile app with Nativescript and now I wanna make the Web App with the code sharing in between both.

Answer (score 0):

I did almost the same a couple of days ago, and while not exactly standard, my approach has been:

- create a new shared web/mobile project from scratch.
- move angular components from the mobile-only project to the shared project.
- rename all HTML files to `.tns.html` ( probably you should rename SCSS/CSS files too, I didn't have any)
- create empty HTML files for each component you have added
- adapt `app.module.ts` and `app.module.tns.ts` to include the new components and any service. `app.module.tns.ts` should very closely resemble the one of the mobile-only app.
- build and resolve errors when they appear. If possible, keep webpack watch files for both mobile and web build, so that you can resolve errors for both platforms.