# How to migrate existing NativeScript app into web app - Code split

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

In the [official documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/intro), there are only examples of how to migrate Web app into NativeScript but I want to migrate existing NativeScript into a Web app.

I can not find a solution anywhere on the internet. Is it even possible to do it in the opposite way or only from WEB to NativeScript?

I tried to do the same process inside my NativeScript project but I'm not able to use any of `@angular/cli` commands.

Comment: You can also see and participate here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/55194747/3157899

Answer (score -1):

I have done the same for one of my previous mobile only {NS} project. Initially it was not a smoth ride but once you are settled, it is very time-saving to use same code base for both Web and mobile. Here are the steps I would suggest based on my experience.

1. You should be using @angular/cli@6.1.0 or newer. `npm i -g @angular/cli`
2. Installl nativescript-schematics. `npm i -g @nativescript/schematics`
3. Create a new Project. `ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics my-mobile-app` (I did it in this way and then copied over src/app folder here from Mobile app).
4. Copy the app/src folder from existing project. (You may want to look for source folder in nsconfig.json `"appPath": "app"`)
5. Find the .ts file where you are using mobile specific components and create a [wrapper class](https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/code-splitting#helper-file) for the same. E.g. I was using [Fancy Alerts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-fancyalert) for mobile apps, so I created a wrapper helper class like helper.tns.ts and helper.ts

in helper.ts

```
public show() {
    alert('Javascript+HTML alert')  .
  }
```

in helper.tns.ts

```
public show() {
    TNSFancyAlert.showWarning('Warning!', 'Message', `Ok`, 0, 300).then(() => {
         resolve('Success');
    });  
  }
```

5. Rename all .html to .tns.html and create web specific html files.

Build a web app

```
ng serve
```

Build a Mobile app

```
tns run android --bundle
tns run ios --bundle
```

P.S. `--bundle` is the key here to compile mobile specific files only. The HTML code that defines the View of the component should be different between a web and a mobile app.